# Can ZF prove choice over families of sets of ordinal definable sets?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Suppose that $X$ is a family of sets of ordinal definable sets.

Can ZF prove the existence of a choice function over $X$?

To put the question formally:

> Is the following a theorem of ZF?  $$\forall X : \forall y \in \bigcup X (y \text{ is ordinal definable}) \\ \to \exists f (f: X \setminus \{\emptyset\} \to \bigcup X, \forall x (f(x) \in x)) $$

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Is the family a family of OD sets? Is the family itself OD? Are the elements of the sets in the family themselves OD? There are three "levels" here, which ones are OD?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, the formula clarify this, its the third option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class $\sf OD$ is just the closure of $\{V_\alpha\mid\alpha\in\rm Ord\}$ under Gödel operations (see Jech's Set Theory section on "*Ordinal Definable Sets*").

This means there is a definable well-ordering of $\sf OD$ by means of recursive construction of the definition.

Therefore, if $\bigcup X\subseteq\sf OD$, then there is a definable choice function from $X$.